# Any idea how to decode this binary data?

Tags: unpacking, file-format

I have binary data representing a table.

Here's the data when I print it with Python's [repr()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html#module-repr):
`\xff\xff\x05\x04test\x02A\x05test1@\x04\x03@@\x04\x05@0\x00\x00@\x05\x05test2\x03\x05\x05test1\x06@0\x00\x01@\x00`

Here's what the table looks like in the proprietary software.

<kbd>test1</kbd>        
        <kbd>test1</kbd><kbd>test1</kbd>
<kbd>test</kbd>          <kbd>test1</kbd>
<kbd>test1</kbd>                
<kbd>test1</kbd><kbd>test2</kbd>        
                        
                        
<kbd>test1</kbd>                
<kbd>test1</kbd>                
<kbd>test1</kbd>                
        <kbd>test1</kbd>        
        <kbd>test1</kbd>        
                        
                        
<kbd>test1</kbd>                
<kbd>test1</kbd>

I was able to guess some of it:

- It's column by column then cell by cell, starting at the top left cell.
- The `\x04` in `\x04test` seems to be the length (in bytes I guess) of the following word.
- `@` mean the last value

Anyone knows if the data is following a standard or have any tips how to decode it?

Thanks!

Here's an example with python :

```
from struct import unpack


def DecodeData(position):
    print "position", position
    firstChar = data[position:][:1]
    size_in_bytes = unpack('B', firstChar)[0]
    print "firstChar: {0}. size_in_bytes: {1}".format(repr(firstChar), size_in_bytes)
    return size_in_bytes


def ReadWord(position, size_in_bytes):
    word = unpack('%ds' % size_in_bytes, data[position:][:size_in_bytes])[0]
    print "word:", word

data = "\xff\xff\x05\x04test\x02A\x05test1@\x04\x03@@\x04\x05@0\x00\x00@\x05\x05test2\x03\x05\x05test1\x06@0\x00\x01@\x00"

position = 0

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\xff - ?"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x05 - ?"

print ""
position += 1
size_in_bytes = DecodeData(position)
position += 1
ReadWord(position, size_in_bytes)


print ""
position += size_in_bytes
DecodeData(position)
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print """'2A' : could be to say that "test" has 2 empty cells before it"""

print ""
position += 1
size_in_bytes = DecodeData(position)
position += 1
word = unpack('%ds' % size_in_bytes, data[position:][:size_in_bytes])[0]
print "word:", word

position += size_in_bytes

DecodeData(position)
print """@: mean that there's another "test1" cell"""

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x04\\x03 - Could be that the next value is 3 cells down"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print ""
position += 1
print "@@ - Seems to mean 3 repetitions"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x04\\x05 - Could be that the next value is 5 cells down"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "@ - repetition"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x00\\x00 - That could mean to move to the first cell on the next column"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "@ - repetition"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x05 - ?"

print ""
position += 1
size_in_bytes = DecodeData(position)
position += 1
word = unpack('%ds' % size_in_bytes, data[position:][:size_in_bytes])[0]
print "word:", word
position += size_in_bytes

print ""
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x03 - Could be to tell that the pervious word 'test2' is 3 cells down"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x05 - ?"

print ""
position += 1
size_in_bytes = DecodeData(position)
position += 1
word = unpack('%ds' % size_in_bytes, data[position:][:size_in_bytes])[0]
print "word:", word
position += size_in_bytes

print ""
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x06 - Could be to tell that the pervious word 'test1' is 6 cells down"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "@ - repetition"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\0 - ?"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x00\\x01 - Seems to mean, next column second cell"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "@ - repetition"

print ""
position += 1
DecodeData(position)
print "\\x00 - end of data or column"
```

Comment: Do you have the module itself? It would be almost trivial to disassemble the `repr` function, assuming this is registered the normal way it is in C extension modules.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "module". But here's the data in HEX 0xFFFF050474657374024105746573743140040340400405403000004005057465737432030505746573743106403000014000. I'm using repr() only to get rid of the 'Decode error - output not utf-8' message in python so you can ignore that.

Comment: The data belongs to some kind of object and that usually belongs to a module, such as the ones you `import` in Python ;)

Comment: The data is from a [varbinary](max) field in a MSSQL database which is used by a proprietary and uncooperative software.

Comment: It would make sense to have the software that processes the data. [See here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261). Basically **too little info** to help you.

Comment: I don't have the code of the proprietary software but I added some python code that I use to try to figure out the structure.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to this newbie (me) if a few different examples of the data could be provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an explanation for what I think the individual symbols mean. I'm basing this around the presumption that a little selector is going through the cells, one by one.

- `\xFF` = Null cell
- `\x05` = A string is following, with `\xNumber` coming after the string to define how far to displace the string from the selector's current position, if at all.
- `\xNumber string` = A string of length number
- `\x2A` = Could be a byte that says not to displace the current string, and also to assume that the next piece of data is defining a string to be placed in the next cell. Questionable meaning.
- `\x04 \xNumber` = Move selector ahead `\xNumber` cells and place previous string into there.
- `0 \x00 \x0Number` = New column, move selector into row `\xNumber`, and place previous string into there.
  `@` = Place previously used string in the cell following the current one.

So here's my interpretation of the data you're giving us:

- `\xFF\xFF` = two null cells
- `\x05` = A cell, singular, with a string, placed following the null cells, because of the `\x2A` following the string
- `\x04 test` = The string.
- `\x2A \x05 test1` = Another string placed into the cell following. No number needed, since \x2A implies that it's being placed right after "test"
- `@` = Place "test1" into the cell after the "test1" string was first placed.
- `\x04 \x03` = Move selector ahead three cells and place test1 where it lands.
- `@@` = Place into the two cells following also.
- `\x04 \x05 @` = Skip four cells, place into two cells.
- `0` = New column.
- `\x00 \x00 @` = Using string last defined (test1), place into first two cells of the column.
- `\x05 \x05 test2 \x03` = Place a cell three cells afterwords.
- `\x05\x05test1\x06` = Place test1 into a cell 6 after test2
- `@` = Place test1 again, too.
- `0` = move to next column
- `\x00\x01` = Place previous string at location 01
- `@` = And also at location 02
- `\x00` = Done

Explanation: My method was to look for a pattern, check if the pattern withstood further scrutiny - the first pattern I checked seemed to - and clear up any minor issues I had with it. Seems to have worked.

Comment: Please format your answers properly. @0xC0000022L did it for you this time.